# Get local network ip addresses on NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, ip-address

I need to get the info.(private ip address and MAC) of who made a request to a nodeJS server. This is running on an intranet, so i suppose i could get the MAC data somehow, and the ip from `os.networkinterfaces() or req.connection` isnt useful to me since they give me the server or the public ip respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[local-devices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-devices)

**Npm**

```
npm install local-devices
```

**Example**

```
// Using a transpiler
import find from 'local-devices'
// Without using a transpiler
const find = require('local-devices');
 
// Find all local network devices.
find().then(devices => {
  devices /*
  [
    { name: '?', ip: '192.168.0.10', mac: '...' },
    { name: '...', ip: '192.168.0.17', mac: '...' },
    { name: '...', ip: '192.168.0.21', mac: '...' },
    { name: '...', ip: '192.168.0.22', mac: '...' }
  ]
  */
})
```

Comment: Yeah, i actually ended up using a combination of this, and req.connection, which, if made from an intranet, turns out it does give the private ip; then i linked this ip to find().then, to get the device MAC. Thankyou for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const os = require('os');

function getLocalIP() {
  const ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
  let ipAddress;

  Object.keys(ifaces).forEach((ifname) => {
    ifaces[ifname].forEach((iface) => {
      if (iface.family === 'IPv4' && !iface.internal) {
        ipAddress = iface.address;
      }
    });
  });

  return ipAddress;
}

console.log(`Local IP Address: ${getLocalIP()}`);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).